# Present categories in a monthly table with each column by date with PHP from MySQL query

Tags: php, html

I have two MySQL tables-

```
Data_table
------------------------------------------
ID  |  Cat_ID  |  Name  |   |  OT  |  Date
------------------------------------------

Cat_table
------------------------------
ID  |  Cat_name
------------------------------
```

Now, with PHP, would like to present the data categorically in a monthly table like -

```
-----------------------------------------------------
Cat_name  |         Jan 1           | ...
-----------------------------------------------------
          | -----------------------------------------
          | OT   |  Rate  |  Total  | 
          | -------------------------
CAT_ONE   | 4.0  |   3    |    12   | 
CAT_TWO   | 4.0  |   2    |    08   | ...
.....................................................
                          |    20   |
```

My SQL -

```
SELECT OT, Rate,
    Cat_Name
    FROM Data_table
    INNER JOIN Cat_Table on Data_table.Cat_ID = Cat_table.ID
                    ORDER BY
                        Data_table.date ASC";
```

Doing foreach with PHP on different level or manipulating the StdObj to make different arrays has not been fruitful yet. Could anybody share some trick. Seems legit complex. Some sort of pseudo code would be enough for me.

Comment: make a fiddle with  data and produce a [mre] also tell us what version you have. you will need to do dynamic sql or ctes in myslq 8

Comment: You have three steps here: (1) get the data from MySQL in a useful/convenient structure, (2) process it with PHP into a useful/convenient PHP data structure (using classes or just associative arrays), (3) process the PHP data structures you created to generate the actual HTML (or whatever you're using for UI). Try to start from the end and go backwards to determine what kind of structure each step should provide to the next step.